# Having graphics resize in line with the Frame in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have drawn a box within my JPanel so that it resizes appropriately when the JFrame is resized.

This is how I implement it:

```
public void drawBox(Graphics g){
    int num1 = getWidth()/4, num2 = getHeight()/4, num3 = getWidth() - num1, 
            num4 = getHeight() - num2;
    g.drawLine(num1, num2, num3, num2);
    g.drawLine(num1, num2, num1, num4);
    g.drawLine(num3, num2, num3, num4);
    g.drawLine(num1, num4, num3, num4);     
}
```

What I have done works but is there a better way to do this? I'd like general feedback, cleaner code would be my main priority though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Naming and Initialization

It's very hard to read when many variables are initialized on a single line.

`numN` naming pattern is also confusing. Since they correspond to coordinates, why not name them like this?

```
final int topLeftX = getWidth()/4
final int topLeftY = getHeight()/4
final int bottomRightX = ...
```

The `4` number may also be extracted into a vairable.

#### Draw a Rectangle

If I'm not mistaken, with `drawLine(args)` you are trying to draw a rectangle. It may be replaced with the [respective method call](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), thus reducing the stuff to a single line:

```
g.drawRect(topLeftX, topLeftY, width, height);
```